# Rails way for 2 dates ranges with 'or'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

What is the proper way for *where* condition if i need to get rows in range for today and e.g. for yesterday?
I mean something like this:

```
Model.where("created_at ? OR created_at ?", 
             Time.now - 3.hours..Time.now + 3.hours, 
             Time.now - 1.day - 3.hours..Time.now - 1.day + 3.hours)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this:

```
Model.where("(created_at between ? and ?) OR (created_at between ? and ?)",
         DateTime.now - 3.hours, DateTime.now + 3.hours,
         DateTime.now - 1.day - 3.hours, DateTime.now - 1.day + 3.hours)
```

If you didn't have an `OR` you could do:

```
Model.where(:created_at => (DateTime.now - 3.hours)..(DateTime.now + 3.hours))
```

but since you have and `OR` you just have to "write it out" like I show above.

Answer (score 2):

```
Model.where("(created_at between ? and ?) OR (created_at between ? and ?)",
            3.hours.ago,
            3.hours.from_now,
            3.hours.ago.yesterday,
            3.hours.from_now.yesterday)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query using or through Arel

```
 model = Model.arel_table

 Model.where(model[:created_at].eq(DateTime.now - 3.hours..DateTime.now + 3.hours).or(model[:created_at].eq(DateTime.now - 1.day - 3.hours..DateTime.now - 1.day + 3.hours)))
```